# Custom Identity and Continuous 503 on First http Request

Tags: .net, iis, iis-8

There is something preventing me from binding a local/non-domain windows user account to the identity of an IIS app-pool.

There is a website in IIS called "Test" that hosts a single test.html page. I have associated an application pool called "Test" to this website with the default "ApplicationPoolIdentity" as the app-pool identity. When I browse to the site, I get the hello web page.

Next

1. Create a local Windows user account name WebUser and paste the password to notepad.
2. Go to IIS and set the "Test" app-pool identity to the user created in step 1 and paste the password. Here I get and invalid password error, whether I paste the password or type it in.
3. Create a PowerShell script that binds the user to the app-pool - this works, even though the UI fails. (I visual validate that the "WebUser" is now the identity)
4. Open the website and get 503 and black square on app-pool.
5. Add user as a member of IISU_IUSR group.
6. Add user to "Login as Service" security policy.
7. Add user to "Login as Batch" security policy.
8. iisreset /restart
9. Browse "Test" website 503 and black square on app-pool.
10. Restart app pool
    11.Browse "Test" website 503 and black square on app-pool.

On a laptop at my home, I can create a local account and bind it as app-pool identity with no other changes and the website runs without let or hindrance.

Laptop at home is Windows 10 Pro
Laptop at work is Windows 11 Enterprise

Could this be a policy pushed out by corp blocking? Why can I bind a user using PowerShell or appcmd.exe but not the IIS UI?

Comment: "Could this be a policy pushed out by corp blocking" is a good question for your domain administrators. As far as I know many companies even block installation of IIS on machines, so anything similar isn't a surprise. Since no one here has access to your work laptop, I don't think any real discussion can happen.

Comment: I get it, I was just checking to see if there was something obvious that I was missing before making a case. I think it would be easier just to spin up a server instance in my personal account and be done with it. I am trying to forge ahead while waiting on a directory service domain share in our dev/tst environments.

Comment: Typically, I would set the application pool identity directly to the built-in account "ApplicationPoolIdentity". If I need to set the application pool identity to a custom account, then I will create a custom domain user and set it up.

Comment: @YurongDai - That is the end goal. The identity would be a domain service account that can access sql servers and apps can use sspi to connect. I was attempting to do this with a single hop using two local accounts with same username and password.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue?

Comment: @YurongDai - I think it has something to do with a corporate policy. When a new EC2 Windows 2019 Server spins up, I can bind local accounts to the app pool in the powershell init scripts, same with windows server on a VM.